# SELECT always returns something even when the db is empty

Tags: php, mysql

my problem is that always the result is bigger than 0 and all the time he's telling like there is something inside the database, but in fact the database is empty, what could be the reason? I must have done something wrong here.

Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
   header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf8");

   $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password"); //   Your Username and Password
   if(!$connection)
   {
       die("database connection failed:" . mysql_error());       
   }
   $db = mysql_select_db("database_name",$connection); //   The database name
   if(!db)
   {
       die("database connection failed:" . mysql_error());
   }
   mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'",$connection);
?>

<?php

    $varGet1 = $_POST['deviceToken'];
    $varGet2 = $_POST['uniqueIdentifier'];

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `push_notification_users` WHERE uniqueIdentifier = '".$varGet2."'");
    if ($result > 0)
    {
        echo 'UDID found on Database. Not added.'; 
    }
    else
    {
        $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `push_notification_users` (`deviceToken`,`uniqueIdentifier`) VALUES ('".$varGet1."','".$varGet2."')");

        if($result === FALSE)
        {
            die(mysql_error());
        }
        else
        {
            $message = "UDID didnt found on Database. Added successfully";
            echo $message;
        }
    }

    mysql_close($connection);
?>
```

Comment: just see documentation of mysql_query I ma sure that you can answer this question by yourself.

Comment: Think very hard about what exactly `mysql_query` returns and what you're comparing to `> 0` here. *"If database result > 0"* -- what does that even mean?

Comment: You should steer clear from using `mysql_*`. As per PHP docs:"This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used"

Comment: I just know little bit of PHP, that's why I'm asking here. You don't have to give such answers, you could just tell me what I did wrong and help me to repair it that I'll know next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct behavior. mysql_query returns RESOURCE or false on error for select query, and you cannot do `if ($result > 0)`. So if the query is correct, $result casted to int will be always larger than 0. You should use `if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

$result = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `push_notification_users` WHERE uniqueIdentifier = '".$varGet2."'"));
    if ($result >= 1)
    {
        echo 'UDID found on Database. Not added.'; 
    }